# How to find SQL Syntax Error in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am attempting the following SQL Statement in Microsoft Access 2013:

```
INSERT INTO MH_Inspections ([InspectionID],[Surveyed_By],[Certificate_Number],[Owner],[Customer],[Drainage_Area],[Sheet_Number],[PO_Number],[Inspection_Date],[Inspection_Time],[Street],[City],[Location_Details],[Manhole_Number],[Rim_To_Invert],[Grade_To_Invert],[Rim_To_Grade],[Year_Constructed],[Year_Renewed],[Media_Label],[Consequence_Of_Failure],[Date_Cleaned],[AdditionalComponentInfo],[Northing],[Easting],[Elevation],[Coordinate_System],[Evidence_Surcharge],[Cover_Size],[Cover_Size_Width],[Hole_Number],[Cover_Bearing_Surface_Dia],[Cover_Bearing_Surface_Width],[Adjustment_Ring_Height],[Frame_Bearing_Surface_Width],[Frame_Bearing_Surface_Depth],[Frame_Clear_Open_Diam],[Frame_Offset_Distance],[Frame_Depth],[Chimney_Clear_Opening],[Chimney_Depth],[Cone_Depth],[Wall_Diam],[Wall_BySize],[Wall_Depth],[Channel_Installed],[Step_Number],[MH_Use],[Purpose],[PreCleaning],[Weather],[Location_Code],[Inflow_Potential_from_Runoff],[Access_Type],[GPS_Accuracy],[Inspection_Status],[Cover_Shape],[Cover_Material],[Hole_Diameter],[Cover_Frame_Fit],[Cover_Insert_Type],[Adjustment_Ring_Type],[Adjustment_Ring_Material],[Frame_Material],[Frame_Seal_Inflow],[Chimney_Material1],[Chimney_InI],[Chimney_Lining_Interior],[Chimney_Lining_Exterior],[Cone_Type],[Cone_Material],[Cone_Lining_Interior],[Cone_Lining_Exterior],[Wall_Material],[Wall_Lining_Interior],[Wall_Lining_Exterior],[Bench_Present],[Bench_Material],[Bench_Lining],[Channel_Material],[Channel_Type],[Channel_Exposure],[Step_Material],[Surface_Type_Asphalt],[Cover_Type_Vented],[Cover_Condition_Sound],[Insert_Condition_Sound],[Ring_Condition_Sound],[Frame_Condition_Sound],[Seal_Condition_Sound], [InspectionLevel], [ReportFileName]) 
VALUES (74777,"WTC/ATHOMPSON","U-0819-70306429","CoM",null,"WS04",1,"78.0152","2022-07-22","11:02","ATLANTIC ","MEMPHIS ","ATLANTIC AND HARDIN DR","WS040308",6.4,6.4,0,null,null,null,null,"2022-07-22","CHIMNEY AND CONE ARE CONCRETE BLOCK ",null,null,null, ,"N",24,4,4,23.75,23.75,null,1,1,22,0,8,25,11,4.1,48,null,5.5,"YES",3,"SS","F","Z",1,"C","S","AMH","M","RI","C","CAS","B","G","N","N",null,"CAS","N","ZZZ","N","N","N","CC","ZZZ","N","N","XXX","C","N","Y","XXX","C","CN","F","F","M",true,true,true,true,true,true,true, "2", "WS040308_MACP_WTC_20220722.pdf")
```

I get the following error:

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

I can't figure out where the syntax error is located. Any ideas? I've tried a few online validators and about 50% indicate an error (but don't tell me where), and the other 50% state that its valid SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you format your query, you realize that there is a double `,,`

I used [Instant SQL Formatter](https://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm).

```
INSERT INTO mh_inspections
            ([inspectionid],
             [surveyed_by],
             [certificate_number],
             [owner],
             [customer],
             [drainage_area],
             [sheet_number],
             [po_number],
             [inspection_date],
             [inspection_time],
             [street],
             [city],
             [location_details],
             [manhole_number],
             [rim_to_invert],
             [grade_to_invert],
             [rim_to_grade],
             [year_constructed],
             [year_renewed],
             [media_label],
             [consequence_of_failure],
             [date_cleaned],
             [additionalcomponentinfo],
             [northing],
             [easting],
             [elevation],
             [coordinate_system],
             [evidence_surcharge],
             [cover_size],
             [cover_size_width],
             [hole_number],
             [cover_bearing_surface_dia],
             [cover_bearing_surface_width],
             [adjustment_ring_height],
             [frame_bearing_surface_width],
             [frame_bearing_surface_depth],
             [frame_clear_open_diam],
             [frame_offset_distance],
             [frame_depth],
             [chimney_clear_opening],
             [chimney_depth],
             [cone_depth],
             [wall_diam],
             [wall_bysize],
             [wall_depth],
             [channel_installed],
             [step_number],
             [mh_use],
             [purpose],
             [precleaning],
             [weather],
             [location_code],
             [inflow_potential_from_runoff],
             [access_type],
             [gps_accuracy],
             [inspection_status],
             [cover_shape],
             [cover_material],
             [hole_diameter],
             [cover_frame_fit],
             [cover_insert_type],
             [adjustment_ring_type],
             [adjustment_ring_material],
             [frame_material],
             [frame_seal_inflow],
             [chimney_material1],
             [chimney_ini],
             [chimney_lining_interior],
             [chimney_lining_exterior],
             [cone_type],
             [cone_material],
             [cone_lining_interior],
             [cone_lining_exterior],
             [wall_material],
             [wall_lining_interior],
             [wall_lining_exterior],
             [bench_present],
             [bench_material],
             [bench_lining],
             [channel_material],
             [channel_type],
             [channel_exposure],
             [step_material],
             [surface_type_asphalt],
             [cover_type_vented],
             [cover_condition_sound],
             [insert_condition_sound],
             [ring_condition_sound],
             [frame_condition_sound],
             [seal_condition_sound],
             [inspectionlevel],
             [reportfilename])
VALUES      (74777,
             "wtc/athompson",
             "u-0819-70306429",
             "com",
             NULL,
             "ws04",
             1,
             "78.0152",
             "2022-07-22",
             "11:02",
             "atlantic",
             "memphis",
             "atlantic and hardin dr",
             "ws040308",
             6.4,
             6.4,
             0,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             "2022-07-22",
             "chimney and cone are concrete block",
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,,
"n",
24,
4,
4,
23.75,
23.75,
NULL,
1,
1,
22,
0,
8,
25,
11,
4.1,
48,
NULL,
5.5,
"yes",
3,
"ss",
"f",
"z",
1,
"c",
"s",
"amh",
"m",
"ri",
"c",
"cas",
"b",
"g",
"n",
"n",
NULL,
"cas",
"n",
"zzz",
"n",
"n",
"n",
"cc",
"zzz",
"n",
"n",
"xxx",
"c",
"n",
"y",
"xxx",
"c",
"cn",
"f",
"f",
"m",
true,
true,
true,
true,
true,
true,
true,
"2",
"ws040308_macp_wtc_20220722.pdf")
```